# Converting special characters into html jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to Convert special characters to HTML in jquery but am not getting any result in my website

```
<textarea id="Mpreditor">  &amp;lt;tr&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
            &amp;lt;/tbody&amp;gt;
                &amp;lt;tfoot&amp;gt;
                    &amp;lt;tr&amp;gt;
                        &amp;lt;td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
                        &amp;lt;td class=&amp;quot;comment-form&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
</textarea>
```

**Jquery code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){

var html = $("#Mpreditor").html();
html = html.replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;','>').replace('&quot;','"');
$("#Mpreditor").html(html);

}
</script>
```

Here in jsfiddle is working but in my website is not working 
https://jsfiddle.net/codesoft/426njvsx/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, please check this out.

```
var needToConvert = 'But I want to turn "&lt;" and "&gt;" into "<" and ">".';

var convert = function(convert){
    return $("<span />", { html: convert }).text();
    //return document.createElement("span").innerText;
};

alert(convert(needToConvert));
```

Answer (score -1):

You code is working try this,

```
  function convertthings(){


    var convert = function(convert){
        return $("<span />", { html: convert }).text();
        //return document.createElement("span").innerText;
    };

    alert(convert(document.getElementById('Mpreditor').value));
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="GET" onsubmit="convertthings()">

    <textarea id="Mpreditor">  &amp;lt;tr&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/tr&amp;gt;
                &amp;lt;/tbody&amp;gt;
                    &amp;lt;tfoot&amp;gt;
                        &amp;lt;tr&amp;gt;
                            &amp;lt;td&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/td&amp;gt;
                            &amp;lt;td class=&amp;quot;comment-form&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
    </textarea>

    <input type="submit" id="save_run" value="Run" />
    </form>
```

Comment: i don't understand this answer this is not my question you are doing another thing

Comment: you want to convert &lt and &gt to "<" and ">" for genrate tags.As I understand